# mongodb stitch browser sdk AwsServiceClient undefined

Tags: mongodb-atlas, mongodb-stitch

Why is AwsServiceClient undefined?

```
npm install mongodb-stitch-browser-sdk (4.7.1)
npm install mongodb-stitch-browser-services-aws-s3 (4.7.1)
import { Stitch, AwsServiceClient, AwsRequest } from "mongodb-stitch-browser-sdk";
```

I am trying to upload a photo via stitch to S3.

Comment: Have you set AWS a 3rd party service in the console i.e. added the necessary credentials from AWS?

Comment: Yes, code works well from a stitch function but not from the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to install the `mongodb-stitch-browser-services-aws` sdk to be able to use the `AwsServiceClient`:

```
npm install mongodb-stitch-browser-services-aws

import { AwsServiceClient } from 'mongodb-stitch-browser-services-aws';
```